# Excert ( the_excerpt(); ) Not working properly

Tags: custom-post-types, excerpt, blog

I am creating custom theme, I have included excerpt in the index file

```
<article class="post">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

    <p class="post-info"><?php the_time('F j, Y g:i a'); ?> | by <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a></p>        

    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>         
</article>
```

This will create result like this

[image: Fig 1]

But when I click the heading of the post it will redirect to the post page correctly but **only 55 words are displaying** See below screen shot

[image: Fig 2]

Comment: Which file did you edit for adding `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>`

Comment: <?php the_excerpt(); ?> added in my index.php File

Comment: Okay, then in your `single.php`, make sure you `<?php the_content(); ?>` instead of `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>`.

Comment: If you don't have a single.php, make a copy of your index.php and rename it single.php and then just change `the_excerpt()` with `the_content()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you adding this code in `content.php` then you should use conditions.

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```